# VBA to seach for multiple criteria, and delete the columns that do not contain these criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have put together the below, but I am not familiar with VBA, so it obviously doesn't work.

```
Sub DeleteUneededColumn()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = "Type"
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("page 1").Range("A:ZZ")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
            Rng.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

As per the title, it needs to find multiple criteria (Ideally based on some keywords I have entered in cells `A1:A3` on `Sheet1`), I tried to get it working with just one first but no joy. Then, for every column in `page 1` that doesn't contain these words, delete that column.

I understand `.Find` is going to be a big part of it but not sure on the rest.

Comment: Find is generally a good way to go, but I'm not sure in this case because you are wanting to capture the ranges which Find does not find, if that makes sense. Using Find though you could turn FindString into an array of search terms, loop through them, and record the column number of every result returned by Find, and at the end loop though and delete every column except them. You need to adapt your Find code to return multiple results. There are many examples around.

Answer (score 1):

Find returns the range with first occurrence where the string is found and you're searching the full range.

I modified your code so it goes column by column and collects all columns where the string is not found, then deletes that range.

```
Sub DeleteUneededColumn()

Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range

FindString = "C"

Dim rngCol As Range, rngDelete As Range

For Each rngCol In Range("A:ZZ").Columns
    Set Rng = rngCol.Find(What:=FindString, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        If rngDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDelete = rngCol
        Else
            Set rngDelete = Union(rngDelete, rngCol)
        End If
    End If

Next

rngDelete.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: can you come up with a case, where your solution fails? :) Just curious?

Comment: Excellent, I have got this working fine, but now I need to adapt it for multiple search criteria, specified by certain cells (A1, A2, A3) in another sheet

Comment: Find, check if range is nothing, do second search, check if range is nothing, do third search, check if range is nothing then add to rngDelete. Come on, do i have to do it all for you?